# Keep getting "Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I keep trying to find out how to fix this in my login system but it keeps failing at **$result**, trying to convert it into an array causes my login to fail.

```
    if (isset($_POST['log'])) {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['password']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($rows == 1 && password_verify($password, $result['password'])) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("location: admin.php");
        } else {
            echo "Incorrect details!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You must stop using `mysqli_real_escape_string`. It will cause you bugs in your code. Just use prepared statements like everyone else

Comment: Please do not put answer parts in the question post

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to count the result without **fetching** them. Try below:

Change

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);
```

to

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_all(mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql), MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```